# (Classic) Blazor WebAssembly project in .NET 8

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

With the launch of .NET 8 and VS2022 updated, I'm quite lost of how can I create a mimic of the old .Net 7 Hosted Web Assembly project.

I don't need the new interactivity Blazor features, just the classic architecture, but running on .NET 8.

Comment: If you just want Controllers then I just answered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77486509/). That will come close, pick  'webassembly' and 'global' for the interactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new "Web App" template comes close. You can [add Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77486509/) and a Shared class library. But there is no PWA support.

You can still use the old template from the command line:

```
 dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted --pwa
```

that will then be .net 7 but you can edit the .csproj files (3x) to `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>` and the packages to 8.0.0

The project/folder structure has changed here and there but that is largely cosmetic. You can make most of those changes manually.

Comment: Does this mean they have discontinued support for the classic BlazorWASM?